# Zero-index problem and filtering issue in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I am trying to build a shiny app with an interactive network, but I am stuck with two problems.

Firstly, I cannot figure out why I do have problem with zero indexing, because I used the solution to fix it, but it does not work properly. On the other hand, I do something wrong maybe.

Secondly, I have an issue with filtering the nodes based on the group (list_initiators$factions). Currently, the graph reacts when I want to change “connections”, but it has some malfunctions with factions. I want the graph to display only nodes from factions, which do have the connections. When I untick some factions in sidebox, the graph freezes when there is no connections and it doesn't react properly. You can see that in a table as well.

Here is my code

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(networkD3)

list_initiators <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Okssana/shiny_app_network/master/nodes_amends_20_09_2020.csv", fileEncoding = "Windows-1251") %>%
  select(-X)

edges_for_gephy <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Okssana/shiny_app_network/master/edges_amends_20_09_2020.csv") %>% 
  select(-X)


# UI ####
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      checkboxGroupInput('factions_input', 
                         'Choose faction',
                         choices = unique(list_initiators$factions),
                         selected = unique(list_initiators$factions)),
      
      sliderInput("amends_connection",
                  "Connections",
                  min = 1, 
                  max = 15,
                  value = 5)),
    
    mainPanel(forceNetworkOutput("network_amends"),
              tableOutput("table_nodes"), 
              tableOutput("table_edges")
    )
  )
)


# server ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Download data
  list_initiators <- as.data.frame(list_initiators)
  edges_for_gephy <- as.data.frame(edges_for_gephy)
  
  # Nodes\vertices  
  nodes_rea <-reactive({
    
    nodes_reactive <- list_initiators%>%
      filter(factions %in% input$factions_input) 
  })
  
  # Edges\links   
  links_rea <-reactive({
    
    edges_reactive <- edges_for_gephy%>%
      filter(Value >= input$amends_connection) 
    
  })
  

# Render tables showing content of uploaded files 
output$table_edges <- renderTable({
  links_rea() # Edges
})

output$table_nodes <- renderTable({
  nodes_rea() #Nodes
})

output$network_amends <- renderForceNetwork({
  links1 <-links_rea()
  # These three lines have to solve problem with zero-indexing, but it doesn't work 
  # I still have this warning: It looks like Source/Target is not zero-indexed. This is required in JavaScript and so your plot may not render.
  links1$Source <- match(links_rea()$Source, nodes_rea()$ID_mps)-1
  links1$Target <- match(links_rea()$Target, nodes_rea()$ID_mps)-1
  
  forceNetwork(Links = links1, # source target   value
               Nodes = nodes_rea(), # name
               Source = "Source",
               Target = "Target", 
               Value = "Value",
               Group = "factions", # Colors
               NodeID = "names_mps",
               Nodesize = "weight_name",
               opacity = 1, 
               fontSize = 18, 
               zoom = T,  
               legend = TRUE,
               bounded = TRUE,
               charge=-10)
  
})


}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Comment: `list_initiators <- read.csv(...)` returns on my computer an empty dataset

Comment: @Waldi Weird. The link works properly https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Okssana/shiny_app_network/master/nodes_amends_20_09_2020.csv

Comment: probably an encoding problem : I don't see the characters in the link

Comment: This is what I see : "����� ����� ��������","��","",5

Comment: fileEncoding = "Windows-1251" , It is mentioned in read.csv() as well

Answer (score 0):

After filtering the nodes data frame (`nodes_rea()`), your links data frame (`links1`/`links_rea()`) will have links/row where the `Source` and/or the `Target` value/s are not found in your nodes data frame, and therefore your match commands to re-index the nodes in your links data frame will result in some `NA` values. Filter out those rows in the links data frame that have `NA`s first and it should work, i.e.

```
links1 <- links1 %>% filter(!is.na(Source) & !is.na(Target))
```